# Word VBA: "Ambiguous Name Detected" for ActiveX Labels

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document originally created on a Windows 7 32-bit machine, that is now giving me problems since switching to Windows 7 64-bit.  Both systems are running Word 2010 (v14.0.7173.5000, 32-bit).  The Word document has many ActiveX Labels, and a large macro which links each ActiveX Label to a specific cell in an Excel document.  This way I update the Excel file, and I run the Word macro to update all the labels.

Here is how the ActiveX Labels look in VBA when the Word document is opened on a Win7 x86 machine:

[image]

However when the document is opened on a Win7 x64 machine, the Labels are renamed with a "1" at the end:

[image]

Because there have been no changes to my VBA code itself, if I run the macro I get the error message "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found".  If I try and fix the Labels by removing the "1", I get an "Ambiguous Name Detected" error message.

If I re-save the file with the extra "1" in the Label, the new Labels are retained and visible when opened on a Win7 x86 machine. That same machine is then able to remove the extra "1", but if I try to do the same on a Win7 x64 machine I get the "Ambiguous Name Detected" error message again.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem, and also how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried fixing the handlers to *add* the `1` and then saving (a copy of) the document?

Comment: Not yet. Is there an easy way to do that instead of selecting each label one by one from the pull down menu (like in my screenshots)?

Comment: My VBA code is under the Microsoft Word Object for "ThisDocument", rather than a module.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Makes no difference, I'm talking about the editor itself - [this toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMYzJ.png) (see the tooltips on these two buttons).

Comment: OK there's no difference for me between Procedure View and Full Module View.  I can see my entire VBA code, but I can't change my ActiveX labels unless I select them one at a time from the pulldown (in the Properties - ThisDocument window pane).  I'll have to try this Rubberduck program to see if it helps me out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126647/discussion-between-wongnog-and-mats-mug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your controls need to have their names fixed/changed. You can do this manually in *design mode*.

Or you can update your code so that instead of this:

```
ThisDocument.ai_oos_01.Caption = "whatever"
```

You do this:

```
FixControlNameAndSetCaption "ai_oos_01", "whatever"
```

Just grab this procedure and put it in a standard module (e.g. `Module1`):

```
Public Sub FixControlNameAndSetCaption(ByVal controlName As String, ByVal newCaption As String)
    Dim wordShape As InlineShape
    For Each wordShape In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        With wordShape.OLEFormat.Object
            If Left$(.Name, Len(controlName)) = controlName Then
                If .Name <> controlName Then .Name = controlName
                .Caption = newCaption
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Now, if the controls' `.Name` matches the specified `controlName` exactly, only the `.Caption` will change (which is what your code is currently supposed to be doing). If the controls' `.Name` *would* match the specified `controlName` *if that pesky numeric suffix wasn't there*, then it renames the control to the specified `controlName`, which effectively "cures" your control names.

**HOWEVER**, if you have legit/expected control names `Foobar01` and `Foobar012`, then I don't have a solution other than to strongly recommend you avoid numeric suffixes when naming things, and give things meaningful/descriptive names, always.

The implication of not referring to `ThisDocument.ai_oos_01` directly, is that your code still compiles and runs if the objects somehow get renamed again (I suspect document corruption, or someone duplicated all the controls and/or deleted the original ones, perhaps by accident).